# Transition 1 1/4" PVC conduit through soffit into an attic

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I need to run 2 circuits (50A/240V stove outlet and 30A/240V heat pump water heater) as well as a water pipe bonding conductor along the outside of my house for about 16 feet. The conductors will come from my garage attic (the main panel is in the garage). The whole run is about 80 feet. I'm planning to use #4 Al XHHW-2 for the 50A stove circuit, #2 Al XHHW-2 for the water pipe bonding, #10 Cu THWN-2 for the 30A circuit and a #8 Cu ground wire. I've used the conduit fill calculator and the whole thing fits in a 1 1/4" PVC Schedule 40 conduit with 28.5% fill.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to go from the attic into the conduit outside (see pictures below). There is an outdoor speaker (see green arrow) that has a wire drilled through the soffit. But the slope of the roof in the attic is such that I cannot get closer than about 5-6 feet to the soffit. I could use a fiberglass 'fish stick' to grab a wire coming through the soffit, but there is no way that I can install a box right by the soffit.

Would it work to push a 7 ft section of 1 1/4" LFNC through the soffit from outside and connect it outside with a female threaded PVC coupler to a LL conduit body? I could then potentially grab the flex conduit from the attic and attach is to a junction box and use some Polaris connectors to transition to 4-4-4 Al SER, and 10-3 NM-B.

Any other suggestions on how to approach this?

Thanks

[image: View from attic towards soffit]
[image: Outside view of the house showing planned conduit location]